# Odata filter for JSON object inside another JSON object

Tags: odata, odata-v4

I have a odata service which return a Json object like below and i want to filter data on country. Is it possible?

```js
{
"Name": "Abc",
"Gender": "Male",
"Address": [
              {
                "Street": "Mystreet",
                "City": "Somecity",
                "Country": "Somecountry",
              }
           ]
}
```

I know we can filter it on gender using "service  url ? $filter= Gender eq male" but how do i filter it on country?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an array, you can use the OData functions `any` and `all`. In your case, I would guess that you would want to use `any` (meaning, all people where they have *any* address with this country.

To achieve that with your url, it would be something like this:

```
People?$filter=Address/any(address: address/Country eq 'Somecountry')
```

Here is an example using the example TripPin services that is very similar:
[http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(gl4oqd3rz5uzuqjryt1be5mr))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=AddressInfo/any(address: address/Address eq '187 Suffolk Ln.')](http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(gl4oqd3rz5uzuqjryt1be5mr))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=AddressInfo/any(address:%20address/Address%20eq%20'187%20Suffolk%20Ln.'))

Comment: Hi Tom, any idea how we can apply filter on a property that is not strongly typed basically my child property type is JObject (C#) and the json contains properties like firstname, lastname etc. I won't know these properties upfront as it is a dynamic model , when i try to do something like /api/rows?$filter=child/firstName eq 'abc' , it does not work.

tried this format as well: ?$filter=Data/any(d: d/firstName eq 'abc') , it gives an error firstName not found.